# How to add border radius on the App main view?

Tags: android, ios, react-native

How can I add a border radius on the main view that surround the AppContainer like Snapchat ?

Snapchat has it in all its app

I tried to put a 'border-radius: 20' on the view that surround the AppContainer but it doesn't work.

[image: Snapchat border radius]

Comment: could you share your code you have implemented. But as @VolkanSahin45 answered, React Native uses Camel case, so you can try that out

Answer (score 0):

This might be a typo error because You need a unit measurement or percentage to correctly use border-radius. Hope this helps.

```
border-radius: 20px;
```

Answer (score 0):

In React - Native CSS attributes written as Camel Case so you should try `"borderRadius: 20"`